# How do you write a drush alias for a local Vagrant box?

Tags: drush, virtual-machine, ssh

I'm trying to write a simple drush alias to connect to a Drupal site running on a local Vagrant instance.

I have the following in a file called `~/.drush/l.aliases.drushrc.php`:

```
$aliases['o'] = array(
  'parent' => 'l',
  'root' => '/vagrant/docroot',
  'remote-host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'remote-user' => 'vagrant',
  'ssh-options' => '-p 2222 -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key',
  'uri' => '127.0.0.1:8080',
);
```

The alias is found. `drush sa` returns:

```
l
l.o
```

However, when I `drush @l.o status` it doesn't connect to the remote host:

```
PHP executable        :  /usr/local/bin/php
PHP configuration     :  /usr/local/etc/php/5.3/php.ini
PHP OS                :  Darwin
Drush version         :  6.1.0
Drush configuration   :
```

I have confirmed that this command successfully connects to vagrant:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Debugging output doesn't show an SSH command so far as I can tell:

```
SIG-106:ilob justin$ drush --debug @l.o status
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 3.78 MB]                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 3.98 MB] [bootstrap]
Loaded alias @l.o from file /Users/justin/.drush/l.aliases.drushrc.php [0.01 sec, 3.99 MB]                                                                        [notice]
Cache MISS cid: 6.1.0-commandfiles-0-807b6772846e18b2741e8d5b7119b4cc [0.01 sec, 4 MB]                                                                             [debug]
Cache SET cid: 6.1.0-commandfiles-0-807b6772846e18b2741e8d5b7119b4cc [0.01 sec, 4.02 MB]                                                                           [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.05 sec, 9.56 MB]                                                                                                                      [bootstrap]
Found command: core-status (commandfile=core) [0.08 sec, 9.56 MB]                                                                                              [bootstrap]
Loading outputformat engine. [0.13 sec, 9.6 MB]                                                                                                                   [notice]
Calling hook drush_core_status [0.14 sec, 9.65 MB]                                                                                                                 [debug]
Returned from hook drush_core_status [0.14 sec, 9.66 MB]
```

I know I must be doing something stupid but I just can't see it.

Comment: What does `drush --debug @l.o status` show?  The exact ssh command should be buried in the output.

Comment: FWIW, I always use .ssh/config for setting up SSH connection info instead of the drush options.

Comment: Hmm, there is no ssh command of any kind in the debug output. Debug added above.

Comment: Do other non-Vagrant, but remote, aliases work?  The debug you posted shows that it didn't even attempt the remote connection (you should see lines beginning 'Begin redispatch via invoke process' and 'Backend invoke: ssh ...'

Comment: Yes, I have many and they all do.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to use drush alias with following configuration:

Let's assume two things:

- vagrant box has some sort of static ip (can be private, for example: 192.168.56.101)
- IP of vagrant is available in symbolic form (for example, we have single line in /etc/hosts with ip and hostname). (for example: test.site.local).

Step 1:
We need to copy settings, generated by vagrant ssh-config command into $HOME/.ssh/config

```
Host test.site.local
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    IdentityFile [path to vagrant private insecure key]
```

Step 2:
With such configuration, my alias was in following form:

```
$aliases['example'] = array(
   'root' => '/var/www',
   'uri' => 'test.site.local',
   'remote-host' => 'test.site.local',
   'remote-user' => 'vagrant',
   'ssh-options' => "-i path_to_insecure_private_key"
);
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution. I didn't specify any ssh-options in my alias file having used "vagrant ssh-config", everything I needed was there.

Comment: This worked nicely, though in my case I had to set root like so: 'root' => '/vagrant/docroot'

Comment: Using `/dev/null` as the known hosts file results in a warning every time drush is run. I point it to `HOME/.ssh/known_hosts_vagrant` to use a separate file. Then the warning is only shown once.

Answer (score 3):

The character `~` is expanded by Bash.  Drush does not provide this same service, so you should replace `~` with the path to your home directory.

So, for example:

```
$home = drush_server_home();
$aliases['o'] = array(
  'parent' => 'l',
  'root' => '/vagrant/docroot',
  'remote-host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'remote-user' => 'vagrant',
  'ssh-options' => "-p 2222 -i $home/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key",
  'uri' => '127.0.0.1:8080',
);
```

That's untested, but it should work, baring any simple typo's.

**UPDATE:**

I think I see a Drush bug here.  Drush is going to assume that 127.0.0.1 is going back to the local machine, and will decide not to use ssh w/out even considering the implications of the -p in ssh-options.  This is going to require a patch to Drush to fix.  `function drush_is_local_host()` in [environment.inc](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/includes/environment.inc#L578).

**ISSUE ON GITHUB:**

Please put any comments regarding potential fixes in the Github issue, [Drush backend invoke does not consider port number when deciding local vs remote](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/545).

Comment: That didn't work. But I didn't know about drush_server_home(). Thanks! I'm troubleshooting.

Comment: c.f. https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/546

Answer (score 3):

I got around this by simply doing a check for Drush in my [local settings.php file](http://www.thirdandgrove.com/blog/2014/07/drupal-settings-done-right.html) via `php_sapi_name() == 'cli'` and updating my database and memcache connection strings to Vagrant, like this:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
  $databases['default']['default']['port'] = '3307';

  $conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
    '127.0.0.1:11212' => 'default',
  );
}
```